# How to select all rows as default with checkmark?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to select all rows when the view appear, i used index path in `viewDidAppear` but it only selected one row and without Checkmark
Here's my `viewDidAppear` method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Select Blood Donors";
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [_tblResult selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

My table view methods :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdent = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdent];

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([arSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) { cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; } else { cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [arSelectedRows addObject:indexPath];

    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [arSelectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in arSelectedRows) {
        [selections addObject:[arrName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arrName count];
}
```

Comment: Do you want  to select all checkbox when you click only one checkbox?

Comment: No i want all selected when view will load first, then user will decided which cell to check or not

Comment: you can store a key in arrname array and chage the value according to selection .

Comment: You want to make sure that when view loads first do you want to select all CHECKBOX or all CELL?

Comment: Jack sparrow try my below new answer.It works superbly.

Answer (score 3):

I got output finally according to your question requirement.I tried this for more than 3 hour.If you try this with boolean you can't achieve as you have multiple checkbox.If you have only one checkbox you can easily use the boolean.

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()
 {
    NSMutableArray *arrProduct,*arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark;
 }

 @end

 @implementation SecondViewController

 @synthesize tblviewCheckMark;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     arrProduct = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iOS",@"Android",@"Windows",@"Blackberry",@"Symbian",@"bada",nil];
     arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     for(int j=0;j<[arrProduct count];j++)
     {
         [arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"selected"];
     }
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 #pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return arrProduct.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *strCell = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
    }
    if([[arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   @try
   {
      CGPoint touchPoint = [cell convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tblviewCheckMark];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblviewCheckMark indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
      NSLog(@"%@",arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark);
      if([arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark count]==0)
      {
         for(int i=0; i<[arrProduct count]; i++)
         {
            [arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"select"];
         }
      }
      if([[arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
      {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
         [arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"deselected"];
      }
      else
      {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
         [arrSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"selected"];
      }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
     NSLog(@"The exception is-%@",exception);
    }
}

@end
```

Above code works perfectly.First all select when the view loads after that we can change that.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link :

In which you can find the sample code for the Mutliple rows selection in UItableview and further operations:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Sure @Paulw11 , Thanks for your sugesstions

Comment: @JackSparrow, please ensure you that you have selected the Multiple Selection is enabled in Selection Under Right top of utilities area.                             Please Select ------>your tableview and then go right top corner --->select 4th icon----> look down, in selection tap-->select multiple selection .

Answer (score 0):

You can directly give

`cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;`

**instead of**

```
if([arSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) { 
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
} else { 
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; 
}
```

This will add checkmark to all of your cells. Then you need to handle it when user clicks on a cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i want to checkmark all when view appears , is it possible to do or checkmark applies only when u click on it ?

Comment: This will add checkmark to all cells when view appears. This should be done in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

Create data object with two properties value and isSelected . Your array name is "arrName". Add all the objects in array with default `isSelected=YES`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]].isSelected=YES;
    [tableView reloadData];//or just row
}
```

And in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]].isSelected=NO;
    [tableView reloadData];//or just row
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //initial code
    //addd this code
    if([data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]].isSelected){
      //set checked 
    }else {
      //set unchecked 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use an `NSMutableIndexSet` to store your row selection status.  This way you can manage the appearance of checkmarks independently of row selection:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableIndexSet *checkedRows;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.checkedRows = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.checkedRows addIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,arrName.count-1);
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *cellIdent = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];

    if(cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdent];

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([self.checkedRows containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;   
    }  

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCellAccessory accessory = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;        

    if ([self.checkedRows containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        [self.checkedRows removeIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        [self.checkedRows addIndex:indexPath.row];
        accessory = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = accessory;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this to allow multiple selection :

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Then, do this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_tblResult numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [_tblResult selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Not tested but it should work.

Comment: That just allows us to select multiple rows, i want to pre-select all rows

Comment: Hi , thanks for the code man, but it just selects the row , it does not put the check mark on it :( i tried putting `cell.accessorytype.checkmark = yes;`

Comment: `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` is good for setting checkmark and `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. What's wrong ?